# Postgres - Left join using a where clause + distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to join two tables using a join

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN voted ON posts.post_id = voted.id
```

Which produces this:

[image]

How would I create query using:

```
ORDER BY date_posted DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY
```

**on the Posts Table** to return this result

[image]

**Edit 1**: duplicate post_id

How would I make it so that the uuid on the user_id column is only 82411850-

[image]

**Edit 2**: Final query thanks to Mr.Linoff

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.date_posted, p.posted_by,
   v.user_id, v.votes
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
 voted v
 ON p.post_id = v.id
 AND v.user_id = '82411580...'

ORDER BY p.date_posted DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a collision of ids.  Be explicit about the columns you are selecting.

Then I think you have basically the right logic:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.date_posted, p.posted_by,
       v.user_id, v.votes
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     voted v
     ON p.post_id = v.id
ORDER BY p.date_posted DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but I'm still getting a duplicate on post_id. Unsure why (added a pic above)

Comment: Finally got it, need to add v.user_id = "82411850.." after the ON